# How is the rollout from the MCTS implemented in both of the AlphaGo Zero and the AlphaZero algorithms?

Tags: monte-carlo-tree-search, alphazero, implementation, alphago-zero

In the vanilla [Monte Carlo tree search (MCTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search) implementation, the rollout is usually implemented following a uniform random policy, that is, it takes random actions until the game is finished and only then the information gathered is backed up.

I have read the AlphaZero paper (and the AlphaGo Zero too) and I didn't find any information on how the rollout is implemented (maybe I missed it).

How is the rollout from the MCTS implemented in both the AlphaGo Zero and the AlphaZero algorithms?

Comment: AlphaZero/Go don't have rollout. Rollout replaced with neural network value estimation

Comment: @mi: I thought that original Alpha Go *did* have a rollout policy, but that one of the simplifying changes in AlphaZero was to completely remove it?

Comment: @NeilSlater That's correct. The question seems to be about AlphaGo Zero and AlphaZero though, not about Alpha Go :) **AlphaGo**: uses a fast rollout policy (trained like the policy network, but is not a large DNN, just a single layer + softmax I believe). **AlphaGo Zero**: no rollouts. **AlphaZero**: no rollouts.

Comment: @mirror2image even though it was only a line, you answered the question -- why not make it slightly more verbose and make it an answer

Comment: Thanks for the answers. However, I'm still confused. I understand that they use the V value returned from the network to simulate who won, but how do they know which value of V a player won or lost? Because as far as I understand, in the weight update (in the loss function), they will compare the probability distribution gathered from the self-plays and the difference between the real winner (from MCTS) and the value V.

Comment: In short, I'm confused about the V value range returned from the network. Will it be in the [-1,1] range?

Comment: @ihavenoidea  I got the same question have you figured it out?